# Extract tokens from a string using Java

Tags: java, string

I am writing a Java program to extract tokens from a String like below:
`"My name is ${lastName}, ${firstName}."`

My expected outputs would be an array
`My name is`, `${lastName}`, `,`, `${firstName}`, `.`.

I have written a static method to do this:

```
static List<String> tokenize(String str) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    int idx = -1;
    int beginIndex = 0;
    while ((idx = str.indexOf("${")) > -1) {
        results.add(str.substring(beginIndex, idx));
        str = str.substring(idx + 2);

        idx = str.indexOf("}");
        if (idx > 0) {
            results.add("${" + str.substring(0, idx) + "}");
            str = str.substring(idx + 1);
        }
    }
    results.add(str);
    return results;
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is any open source library that can achieve the same result.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) as it allow you to use a regular expression to split the `String`, which will be much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split

```
String[] data = input.split("(?=\\$)")
```

It will return your data in this format (Array).

```
[My name is , ${lastName}, , ${firstName}]
```

To convert it into a list

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```